# How to catch the L3-cache hits and misses by perf tool in Linux

Tags: linux, caching, cpu, perf

Is there any way to catch the L3-cache hits and misses by perf tool in Linux. According to the output of `perf list cache`, L1 and LLC cache are supported. According to the definition of [perf_evsel__hw_cache](http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/evsel_8c.html#ad29b951a4b280c8e587a3f779656ec62) array in perf's source code:

```
const char *perf_evsel__hw_cache[PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MAX]
                                [PERF_EVSEL__MAX_ALIASES] = {
 { "L1-dcache", "l1-d",         "l1d",          "L1-data",              },
 { "L1-icache", "l1-i",         "l1i",          "L1-instruction",       },
 { "LLC",       "L2",                                                   },
 { "dTLB",      "d-tlb",        "Data-TLB",                             },
 { "iTLB",      "i-tlb",        "Instruction-TLB",                      },
 { "branch",    "branches",     "bpu",          "btb",          "bpc",  },
 { "node",                                                              },
};
```

LLC is an alias to L2-cache. My question is how to catch the L3-cache hits and misses by perf tool in Linux. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your CPU? Newer version of perf and linux kernel may support L3 cache events on some CPUs. Are you sure that "LLC" was alias for L2 and not for L3 (the real meaning may be defined in kernel part of perf code)?

Answer (score 6):

I have had more success using raw event counters, looking directly at the Intel Software Developer Manual for detailed definitions.

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.html

From section:
18.2.1.2 Pre-defined Architectural Performance Events

r412e "LLC Misses" is likely the one you want

```
perf stat -e r412e <command>
```

(Note that for me, this gives the same number as using -e cache-misses.)

Comment: To get system-wide L3 cache miss rate, just do: `sudo perf stat -a -e LLC-loads -e LLC-load-misses -e LLC-stores -e LLC-store-misses -e LLC-prefetch-misses` which prints out both misses and total references.  The ratio is the L3 cache miss rate.

Answer (score 5):

That is strange LLC (Last Level Cache) is configured with "L2" if the hardware has L3 cache. But I don't know yet internals of perf and maybe these settings are generic.

I think the only solution you have is to use "raw hardware event" (see at the end of "perf list", the line starting with "rNNN"). That gives the opportunity to encode a description of the hardware registers.

The perf user guide and tutorial only mention "To measure an actual PMU as provided by the HW vendor documentation, pass the hexadecimal parameter code". I don't know what is the syntax on Intel and if there is different implementations of the performance monitor on this architecture. You could start here:

http://code.google.com/p/kernel/wiki/PerfUserGuide#Hardware_events

Comment: And page http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/hpc-prof-events.html have advises of searching and using raw perf events with help of libpfm4 (perfmon2) utilities `showevtinfo` and `check_events`

Answer (score 2):

To get system-wide L3 cache miss rate, just do:

```
$ sudo perf stat -a -e LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses,LLC-stores,LLC-store-misses,LLC-prefetch-misses sleep 5


Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

    24,477,266,369      LLC-loads                                                     (22.65%)
     1,409,470,007      LLC-load-misses           #    5.76% of all LL-cache hits     (29.79%)
        88,584,705      LLC-stores                                                    (30.32%)
        10,545,277      LLC-store-misses                                              (30.03%)
       150,785,745      LLC-prefetch-misses                                           (34.71%)

      13.773144159 seconds time elapsed
```

This prints out both misses and total references.  The ratio is the L3 cache miss rate.

See complete event list on wiki: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Events

Comment: May i ask what are the LLC-prefetch-misses and how they should be used to the calculation of L3 cache miss rate? So far, my calculation is simply (LLC-load-misses+LLC-store-misses) / (LLC-loads+LLC-stores)