# how to get a trace of physical address for all L3 cache misses

Tags: linux, caching, trace

I need a way to get the physical address of all L3 misses (both user + kernel).  Is that possible using a trace tool like ftrace?

Comment: Looks similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172353/how-to-catch-the-l3-cache-hits-and-misses-by-perf-tool-in-linux)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch the L3-cache hits and misses by perf tool in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172353/how-to-catch-the-l3-cache-hits-and-misses-by-perf-tool-in-linux)

Comment: Not exactly.  I want to know the physical (or virtual) addresses for LLC hits and misses, not just the number of hits and misses.