# Cache line alignment optimization not reducing cache miss

Tags: c++, gcc, caching, optimization, g++

I got this piece of code demonstrating how cache line alignment optimization works by reducing 'false sharing' from http://blog.kongfy.com/2016/10/cache-coherence-sequential-consistency-and-memory-barrier/

**Code:**

```
/*
 * Demo program for showing the drawback of "false sharing"
 *
 * Use it with perf!
 *
 * Compile: g++ -O2 -o false_share false_share.cpp -lpthread
 * Usage: perf stat -e cache-misses ./false_share <loopcount> <is_aligned>
 */

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

#define CACHE_ALIGN_SIZE 64
#define CACHE_ALIGNED __attribute__((aligned(CACHE_ALIGN_SIZE)))

int gLoopCount;

inline int64_t current_time()
{
  struct timeval t;
  if (gettimeofday(&t, NULL) < 0) {
  }
  return (static_cast<int64_t>(t.tv_sec) * static_cast<int64_t>(1000000) + static_cast<int64_t>(t.tv_usec));
}

struct value {
  int64_t val;
};
value data[2] CACHE_ALIGNED;

struct aligned_value {
  int64_t val;
} CACHE_ALIGNED;
aligned_value aligned_data[2] CACHE_ALIGNED;

void* worker1(int64_t *val)
{
  printf("worker1 start...\n");

  volatile int64_t &v = *val;
  for (int i = 0; i < gLoopCount; ++i) {
    v += 1;
  }

  printf("worker1 exit...\n");
}

// duplicate worker function for perf report
void* worker2(int64_t *val)
{
  printf("worker2 start...\n");

  volatile int64_t &v = *val;
  for (int i = 0; i < gLoopCount; ++i) {
    v += 1;
  }

  printf("worker2 exit...\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t race_thread_1;
  pthread_t race_thread_2;

  bool is_aligned;

  /* Check arguments to program*/
  if(argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s <loopcount> <is_aligned>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Parse argument */
  gLoopCount = atoi(argv[1]); /* Don't bother with format checking */
  is_aligned = atoi(argv[2]); /* Don't bother with format checking */

  printf("size of unaligned data : %d\n", sizeof(data));
  printf("size of aligned data   : %d\n", sizeof(aligned_data));

  void *val_0, *val_1;
  if (is_aligned) {
    val_0 = (void *)&aligned_data[0].val;
    val_1 = (void *)&aligned_data[1].val;
  } else {
    val_0 = (void *)&data[0].val;
    val_1 = (void *)&data[1].val;
  }

  int64_t start_time = current_time();

  /* Start the threads */
  pthread_create(&race_thread_1, NULL, (void* (*)(void*))worker1, val_0);
  pthread_create(&race_thread_2, NULL, (void* (*)(void*))worker2, val_1);

  /* Wait for the threads to end */
  pthread_join(race_thread_1, NULL);
  pthread_join(race_thread_2, NULL);

  int64_t end_time = current_time();

  printf("time : %d us\n", end_time - start_time);

  return 0;
}
```

**Expected perf result:**

```
[jingyan.kfy@OceanBase224006 work]$ perf stat -e cache-misses ./false_share 100000000 0
size of unaligned data : 16
size of aligned data   : 128
worker2 start...
worker1 start...
worker1 exit...
worker2 exit...
time : 452451 us

 Performance counter stats for './false_share 100000000 0':

         3,105,245 cache-misses

       0.455033803 seconds time elapsed

[jingyan.kfy@OceanBase224006 work]$ perf stat -e cache-misses ./false_share 100000000 1
size of unaligned data : 16
size of aligned data   : 128
worker1 start...
worker2 start...
worker1 exit...
worker2 exit...
time : 326994 us

 Performance counter stats for './false_share 100000000 1':

            27,735 cache-misses

       0.329737667 seconds time elapsed
```

However, I ran the code myself and got very close run time, the cache miss count is even lower when NOT ALIGNED:

**My result:**

```
$ perf stat -e cache-misses ./false_share 100000000 0
size of unaligned data : 16
size of aligned data   : 128
worker1 start...
worker2 start...
worker2 exit...
worker1 exit...
time : 169465 us

 Performance counter stats for './false_share 100000000 0':

            37,698      cache-misses:u                                              

       0.171625603 seconds time elapsed

       0.334919000 seconds user
       0.001988000 seconds sys


$ perf stat -e cache-misses ./false_share 100000000 1
size of unaligned data : 16
size of aligned data   : 128
worker2 start...
worker1 start...
worker2 exit...
worker1 exit...
time : 118798 us

 Performance counter stats for './false_share 100000000 1':

            38,375      cache-misses:u                                              

       0.121072715 seconds time elapsed

       0.230043000 seconds user
       0.001973000 seconds sys
```

How should I understand this inconsistency?

Comment: I ran my code on CentOS, the CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-10105 CPU @ 3.70GHz.

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistency? Everyone has different machines, and so each numerical experiment will produce different results. Please be more specific as to what we should look for.

Comment: @zkoza He's aligning the data, so it can be fetched faster. That should be true on most hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help since the blog you reference to is in Chinese.  Still, I've noticed that the first figure seems to show a multi-socket architecture. So I made a few experiments.

a) my PC,   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz, single socket, two cores, two threeds per core:

0:

```
time : 195389 us

 Performance counter stats for './a.out 100000000 0':

             8 980      cache-misses:u                                              

       0,198584628 seconds time elapsed

       0,391694000 seconds user
       0,000000000 seconds sys
```

and 1:

```
time : 191413 us

 Performance counter stats for './a.out 100000000 1':

             9 020      cache-misses:u                                              

       0,192953853 seconds time elapsed

       0,378434000 seconds user
       0,000000000 seconds sys
```

Not much difference.

b) Now a 2-socket workstation

> Thread(s) per core:              2
> Core(s) per socket:              12
> Socket(s):                       2
> NUMA node(s):                    2
> Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz

0:

```
time : 454679 us

 Performance counter stats for './a.out 100000000 0':

         5,644,133      cache-misses                                                

       0.456665966 seconds time elapsed

       0.738173000 seconds user
```

1:

```
time : 346871 us

 Performance counter stats for './a.out 100000000 1':

            42,217      cache-misses                                                

       0.348814583 seconds time elapsed

       0.539676000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

The difference is huge.

---

One final remark. You write:

> the cache miss count is even lower when NOT ALIGNED

No, it isn't. Your processor is running various tasks besides your program. Also, you're running 2 threads that may access the cache at different time sequences. All this may influence cache utilization. You'd need to repeat your measurements several times and compare.  Personally, when I see any performance results differing by less than 10%, I consider them indistinguishable.

---

##### Update

I've also made experiments with your code extended to 3 threads so that certainly some of them MUST be running on different cores, hence, sharing only the L3 cache.

I looked at [How to catch the L3-cache hits and misses by perf tool in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172353/how-to-catch-the-l3-cache-hits-and-misses-by-perf-tool-in-linux) and came with this command:

```
 perf stat -e cache-misses,cache-references,LLC-loads,LLC-stores,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-prefetch-misses,L1-dcache-store-misses ./a.out 100000000 0
```

0:

```
time : 214253 us

 Performance counter stats for './a.out 100000000 0':

             4 765      cache-misses:u            #    0,018 % of all cache refs      (57,39%)
        25 992 887      cache-references:u                                            (57,56%)
        17 430 736      LLC-loads:u                                                   (57,56%)
         8 591 378      LLC-stores:u                                                  (57,56%)
        28 110 342      L1-dcache-load-misses:u                                       (57,40%)
        14 661 378      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses:u                                     (57,80%)
            32 269      L1-dcache-store-misses:u                                      (57,49%)

       0,215484922 seconds time elapsed

       0,627426000 seconds user
       0,006635000 seconds sys
```

1:

```
time : 194253 us

 Performance counter stats for './a.out 100000000 1':

             4 509      cache-misses:u            #   30,715 % of all cache refs      (57,15%)
            14 680      cache-references:u                                            (57,45%)
             7 954      LLC-loads:u                                                   (57,49%)
             1 565      LLC-stores:u                                                  (57,92%)
             4 442      L1-dcache-load-misses:u                                       (57,91%)
               836      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses:u                                     (57,02%)
               984      L1-dcache-store-misses:u                                      (56,85%)

       0,195145645 seconds time elapsed

       0,569986000 seconds user
       0,000000000 seconds sys
```

Thus:

- the aligned (3-thread) version runs systematically (a bit) faster than unaligned (I repeated the test several times) even in a single-socket machine.
- it's not quite clear what "cache-misses" option actually reports
- there's a huge (numerical) penalty for "false data sharing" in the L1 cache, LLC cache and in the number of cache references.
- remember that these are hardware-based statistics: if other processes are running, they add their contribution to these results

Comment: makes total sense, thank you.

Comment: I added an update. A very interesting topic. BTW, you may upvote and/or accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I would love to upvote but my reputation is not enough.

Comment: You can accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Anyway, I've learned quite a lot when thinking about this question. Thx.